# xslt @id product to bid relation

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to xsl and have a concrete problem. I have this xml:

```
    <auctions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <products>
    <product id="1">
        <name>Name1</name>
        <description>This is the description of Name1</description>
    </product>
    <product id="2">
        <name>Name2</name>
    </product>
    <product id="3">
        <name>Name3</name>
        <description>This is the description of Name3</description>
    </product>
    <product id="4">
        <name>Name4</name>
        <description>This is the description of Name4</description>
    </product>
 </products>

 <users>
    <user username="Aukuk1"/>
    <user username="Bukuk2"/>
    <user username="Cukuk3"/>
 </users>

 <bids>
    <product id="1">
        <bid user="Aukuk1">400</bid>
        <bid user="Bukuk2">410</bid>
        <bid user="Aukuk1">450</bid>
    </product>
    <product id="2">
        <bid user="Cukuk3">200</bid>
        <bid user="Bukuk2">300</bid>
    </product>
    <product id="3">
        <bid user="Aukuk1">150</bid>
    </product>
 </bids>

</auctions>
```

and I need to get this html output, as follows: All the product names, that have a bid with the descritpion to it, the total number of bids and the bids itself, like this:

```
Name1

This is the description of Name1

Total Bids: 3

400
410
450

Name2

Total Bids: 2

200
300

Name3

This is the description of Name3

Total Bids: 1

150
```

I'm hanging here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<!--<xsl:for-each select="auctions">-->
<xsl:template match="auctions">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="products/product">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
                    </td>
                    <br/>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="description"/>
                    </td>
                    <br/>
                    <td> Total Bids: <span style="color:red">
                            <br/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="max(//auctions//product/bid)"/>
                        </span>
                        <br/>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <br/>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Have you tried `count(//xpath)` to get the node count?

Comment: Please post the expected result **as code**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the XSL you're looking for. It uses a variable within the for-each to properly identify the product ID, then uses that variable to count & iterate over the proper set of bid nodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="auctions">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                <xsl:for-each select="products/product">
                    <xsl:variable name="ProductID" select="@id"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                        </td>
                        <br/>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                        </td>
                        <br/>
                        <td> Total Bids: <span style="color:red"><xsl:value-of select="count(//auctions/bids/product[@id=$ProductID]/bid)"/></span>
                            <br/>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//auctions/bids/product[@id=$ProductID]/bid">
                                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                                <br/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't think that's valid HTML.

Comment: Yes, technically there should be an opening and closing <table> tag but I didn't want to spoon-feed the OP ;-)   The answer is based on the contents of the question but I'll update it to validate as HTML.